# TextBlob - Loop over articles to calculate polarity & subjectivity scores

Tags: python, textblob

I was looking into TextBlob to calculate sentiment scores (polarity, subjectivity) for a list of articles on an excel sheet I've compiled.

Below is an example of the sheet:

> 11/03/2004 04:03 At least 60 people were killed in three bomb attacks
>   on crowded Madrid trains in Spain's worst-ever terrorist attack, said
>   Efe newswire and other media. Red Cross said at least 200 people were
>   injured. ``This is a massacre,'' said Socialist party leader Jose Luis
>   Rodriguez Zapatero, who blamed Basque terrorist group ETA.
>
> 07/07/2005 04:41 London closed its subway system and evacuated all
>   stations after emergency services were called to explosions in and
>   around the financial district.
>
> 01/12/2009 04:00 American International Group, Inc. (AIG) today
>   announced that it has closed two previously announced transactions
>   with the Federal Reserve Bank of New York (FRBNY) that have reduced
>   the debt AIG owes the FRBNY by $25 billion in exchange for the FRBNY’s
>   acquisition of preferred equity interests in certain newly formed
>   subsidiaries.
>
> 22/08/2013 11:38 NASDAQ shuts down for 3 hours due to a computer
>   problem

I've been able to use textblob the most simples way by doing each line individually as so:

```
analysis = TextBlob("NASDAQ shuts down for 3 hours due to a computer problem")
print(analysis.sentiment)
```

What I'd like import my excel file containing date & time and the articles in two columns and move on to loop over each row to calculate polarity and subjectivity scores and save it in the file.

I've tried modifying a code on Thomson Reuters News Analytics this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from textblob import TextBlob

path_to_file = "C:/Users/Parvesh/Desktop/New Project/Sentiment Analysis/events.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file, encoding='latin-1')
df.head()

df['Polarity'] = np.nan
df['Subjectivity'] = np.nan

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

for idx, articles in enumerate(df['articles'].values):  # for each row in our df dataframe
    sentA = TextBlob("articles")  # pass the text only article to TextBlob to analyze
    df['Polarity'].iloc[idx] = sentA.sentiment.polarity  # write sentiment polarity back to df
    df['Subjectivity'].iloc[idx] = sentA.sentiment.subjectivity  # write sentiment subjectivity score back to df
df.head()

df.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

The code is not working though...I'm not getting any scores.

Any advice on how I can this done?

I am a complete newbie to Python (I am using Pycharm). I code mostly on Stata and Matlab.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You should be move the logic into a function, then applying that function to each row of the DataFrame using `pd.Series.map()`. Using `.map()` or `.apply()` is much faster and cleaner than looping through manually.

```
import pandas as pd
from textblob import TextBlob

path_to_file = "C:/Users/Parvesh/Desktop/New Project/Sentiment Analysis/events.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file, encoding='latin-1')
df.head()

# function to extract polarity and subjectivity from text
def process_text(text):
    blob = TextBlob(text)
    return blob.sentiemnt.polarity, blob.sentiment.subjectivity

# apply to each row of the 'articles' Series using the pd.Series.map method
df["polarity"], df["sentiment"] = zip(*df.articles.map(process_text))

df.head()

df.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

Disclaimer: *I haven't tested this.*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out.

I actually got the code working a while back.

This is how it looks:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from textblob import TextBlob

path_to_file = "C:/Users/Parvesh/Desktop/New Project/Sentiment Analysis/events.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file, encoding='latin-1')
df.head()

df['Polarity'] = np.nan
df['Subjectivity'] = np.nan

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

for idx, articles in enumerate(df['articles'].values):  # for each row in our df dataFrame
        ***if articles:***
            sentA = TextBlob(articles) # pass the text only article to TextBlob to analyse
            df['Polarity'].iloc[idx] = sentA.sentiment.polarity # write sentiment polarity back to df
            df['Subjectivity'].iloc[idx] = sentA.sentiment.subjectivity # write sentiment subjectivity score back to df

df.head()

df.to_csv("Sentiment_Scores.csv", index=False)
```

So I was basically missing the ***if articles*** bit which would eventually loop through each article to retrieve the scores.

I highly appreciate you reaching out to my query though.

Thanks a lot!

Regards
Parvesh